# Where is stored the content of a CMS page? How to create a whole new page?

Tags: magento-1.9, page

I created a new page using the admin panel from Magento `CMS->Pages` and created all it's content (html).

Is there another way to do this? I imagine that is something like: Create a file, change `local.xml`, ... something like this? I tried to found the content in a file but I couldn't find it.

Comment: All CMS systems are holding their data (pages, posts...) in db table. To search where exactly you need to access phpMyAdmin. The table that contains cms data is cms_page. Sorry if i misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The content of your CMS page is stored in the **cms_page** table

If you want to create page in Magento you can create from **cms->page** or you can write new controller and create a layout handler in local.xml link phtml page with xml handler

Comment: Is there any tutorial with how to do the controller and the layout handler?

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/programming-magento/magento-hello-world-module-extension/

Answer (score 0):

The content of your CMS page is stored in the database. I don't know the specific table off hand but querying the database for a specific string in the page text should find it quickly.